# lat lon alignment in basemap's pcolormesh method - feature or bug?

Tags: dictionary, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm using Matplotlib and basemap to plot gridded data on a map. I'm comparing the pcolormesh method with a scatter plot using this code:

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
# setup of basemap ('lcc' = lambert conformal conic).
# use major and minor sphere radii from WGS84 ellipsoid.
m = Basemap(width=12000000,height=9000000,
            rsphere=(6378137.00,6356752.3142),\
            resolution='l',area_thresh=1000.,projection='lcc',\
            lat_1=projection['standard_parallel'][0],\
            lat_2=projection['standard_parallel'][1],\
            lat_0=projection['latitude_of_projection_origin'],\
            lon_0=projection['longitude_of_central_meridian'])
x, y = m(lons, lats) # compute map proj coordinates.
# draw coastlines and political boundaries.
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()
# draw parallels and meridians.
# label on left and bottom of map.
parallels = np.arange(0.,80,20.)
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,1])
meridians = np.arange(10.,360.,30.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[1,0,0,1])
#cs = m.pcolormesh(x,y,data) 
cs = m.pcolormesh(x,y,data,shading='flat',cmap=plt.cm.rainbow) 
cb = m.colorbar(cs,"right", size="5%", pad='2%', ticks=V[0::5])
m.scatter(x*data,y*data, marker='.', s=100, c='g')
ax.set_title(title)
plt.show(block=False)
```

The plot I get looks like this:

[image]

Note the lon-lat coordinates correspond to the bottom-left corner of each grid box. Is this by design or is it a bug? I would think by design but then all the examples I see (http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html) make no mention of it. I would like the grid cells centered on the lon lat coordinate points, which are themselves on an irregular grid (the lons, lats variables are 2d arrays). How do I achieve this?

nb. the data variable here is just a mask that corresponds to either ones or nans.

Thanks.

**Edited**: as per Tom's suggestion, if I try contourf I get the following image (zoomed approx to same as first image).

[image]

It still doesn't deal with the edges very well because it cannot draw a surface between a finite value and a nan, so there are a lot of missing points. I want every grid cell to be rendered. It seems that imshow could do what I want, but this seems to only work for regular (linear) grids.

Answer (score 1):

`pcolormesh` takes the nodal coordinates as the `X` and `Y` arguments. From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor) (to `pcolor`, but its the same for `pcolormesh`):

> `X` and `Y`, if given, specify the `(x, y)` coordinates of the colored
>   quadrilaterals; the quadrilateral for `C[i,j]` has corners at:
>
> ```
> (X[i,   j],   Y[i,   j]), 
> (X[i,   j+1], Y[i,   j+1]), 
> (X[i+1, j],   Y[i+1, j]), 
> (X[i+1, j+1], Y[i+1, j+1]).
> ```
>
> Ideally the dimensions of X and Y should be one greater than those of C; if the dimensions are the same, then the last row and column of C will be ignored.

I would suggest averaging the x and y coordinates of each quadrilateral of points in your `x` and `y`, and then using those coordinates for the `scatter`, to centre your points.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly clarifies things. However, my scatter points are already in the correct location. Rather it is the pcolormesh I want to nudge so that each grid cell is centered with the points. Moreover, given that I have irregular lat lon grids, I am not sure how to manually calculate the centroids of each quadrilateral.

Comment: contourf uses cell centres. Would that work for you instead of pcolormesh?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually adjust the lon and lat data to shift them down and to the left by 1/2 of the grid spacing. Then when you plot it, the original lons and lats will be at the center of each pixel. This code also adds one to each dimension of lons and lats arrays, so that they are one greater than the dimensions of the data itself, which the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor) states is ideal.

```
# Subtract 1/2 the grid size from both lon and lat arrays
lons = lons - dlon/2
lats = lats - dlat/2
# Add 1 grid spacing to the right column of lon array and concatenate it as an additional column to the right
lons = np.c_[ lons, lons[:,-1]+dlon ]
# Duplicate the bottom row of the lon array and concatenate it to the bottom
lons = np.r_[ lons, [lons[-1,:]] ]
# Duplicate the right-most column of lats array and concatenate it on the right
lats = np.c_[ lats, lats[:,-1] ]
# Add 1 grid spacing to the bottom row of lat array and concatenate it as an additional row below
lats = np.r_[ lats, [lats[-1,:]+dlat] ]

# Then plot as before
m.pcolormesh(lons, lats, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the lower left corner from 2D center grid point arrays, use the following averaging routine:

```
# adjust xlon,xlat values so they represent corners of grid cells for mapping using pcolor
# calculate average between two points and reassign lat/lon pairs
# skip first row and column of data since there are no points outside of domain to average with

# define empty arrays for storing new lats, lons, and values
corner_lats=np.empty([len(xlat[:,0])-1, len(xlat[0,:])-1],float)
corner_lons=np.empty([len(xlat[:,0])-1, len(xlat[0,:])-1],float)
corner_values=np.zeros([len(xlat[:,0])-1, len(xlat[0,:])-1],float)

# go through each xlat and xlon array and calculate LL corners
for lat in range(1,len(xlat[:,0])-1):
    for lon in range(1,len(xlat[0,:])-1):
        corner_lats[lat,lon]=(xlat[lat,lon]+xlat[lat+1,lon])/2
        corner_lons[lat,lon]=(xlon[lat,lon]+xlon[lat,lon+1])/2
        corner_values[lat-1,lon-1]=data[lat,lon]
```

then when mapping, use the new corner lats,lons, and values:

```
m.pcolor(corner_lons,corner_lats,corner_values,latlon=True)
```